# How to add Admob banner to all the activities in native code using Android Studio?

Tags: java, google-play, admob, banner

I started learning mobile development and I am using Android studio to build.
I just made my first app, then I added AdMob banner in it. I followed the step from the document.
Now I have a problem adding the same throughout all activities in the application.
Do I have to put the same code to every XML layout and activity?
Or is there a way to automatically add banner ads to all app activites?

Comment: [IncludeLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)Using include layout you can also create banner xml once and then include it in all activities.

Answer (score 0):

in this case I recommend creating ad unit for each screen, because the banner will not be shown in the second screen if the first screen uses the same unit ID or it will show the same ad everywhere.

alternatively you can use [native ads](https://admob.google.com/home/resources/native-ads-playbook/) to show ads programmatically in every screen with better user experience.